# How to cut two lips apart

Tags: sculpting

I sculpted character.
Then I found two lips joined together while using remesh. Is there any way I can separate this lip?[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Edit mode, select the line of vertices that go along where you would like to split. Press V to 'rip' the vertices apart. Move them slightly then left click. You can continue sculpting, but your mesh is now non-manifold, so you may wish to model the inside of the mouth at this point.